# Why an element of $SU(2)$ acts as a rotation for the Majorana representation of states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, group-theory, bloch-sphere

I recently asked a [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13163/1011) in quantum computing stack exchange and as suggested by someone in the comments, I decided to ask my question here as well:

I know that for a given spin-j quantum state, say $\vert\psi\rangle = (\psi_0 , \psi_1 , \cdots , \psi_{2j})$, we can construct a polynomial as follows

$
w(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{2j} (-1)^k \psi_k \sqrt{\binom{2j}{k} } z^{2j-k}
$

and by means of the inverse stereographic projection of the roots of $w(z)$, the Majorana representation of $\vert\psi\rangle$ is obtained on sphere. I also know that the Majorana representation for the eigen-state of $\mathbf{J.n}$ operator with eigen-value $m$ is the configuration of points on sphere in which there are $j+m$ points in the $\mathbf{n}$ direction and other $j-m$ points in the antipodal point (equivalently $-\mathbf{n}$ direction).

My question is why the Majorana representation of $e^{i\mathbf{n.J} \theta} \vert \psi \rangle$ is just that of $\vert\psi\rangle$ rotated around $\mathbf{n}$ by an angle of $\theta$? (This is transparent when $\vert \psi \rangle$ is an eigen-vector of angular momentum in some direction but I do not see why this is true in general.)

Answer (score 1):

The holomorphic function $w(z)$ for a spin $j$ state $|w\rangle$ is coherent state
$$
w(z)\equiv \langle z|w\rangle = \langle j,-j| \exp\{zJ_-\}|w\rangle
$$
and the zeros of $w$ are the antipodes of the directions of the individual spin-1/2 states whose symmetric product makes up $|w\rangle$. The magic is of course that Majoranas observation that  unlike higher unitary groups any state in spin-$j$ can be written as a single product of individual spin-1/2's. The SU(2) rotation acts on these states spin-1/2's in the usual way, so it simply rotates the zeros as a rigid assembly.
There is some discussion of this in my [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.2569) with Yun Liu and Abhishek Roy, *Non-Abelian Berry transport, spin coherent states, and Majorana points*, but I'm sure that there other sources as well.

Comment: “ ... that Majoranas observation that unlike higher unitary ..” ?  Do you mean Majorana *representations*?

Comment: “ any state in spin- can be written as a single product of individual spin-1/2” how is this not true for higher unitary groups?  States in any irrep can be constructed by suitable tensor product of the fundamental irrep.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: In represenatations of higher unitary  groups any state can be written as a *sum* of products, not as single product. (Just count the number of degrees of freedom in the $2j+1$ SU(2) and in a single product) .  This has nothing to do with Majorana fermions. The ref is E. Majorana, *Atomi orientati in campo magnetico variabile*  Il Nuovo Cimento, 9 43-50 (1932). This remarkable paper contains the Landau-Zener effect, in addition to the Majorana zeros in  OP's questions".

Comment: Yes of course. I realized this a few hours after posting. I was not thinking about this in the right way when I read your answer although if I understand your point it is still true that states in irreps of the type $(p,0,\ldots,0)$ (or with Young diagram having a single row of $p$ boxes) are precisely of the product type (with no sum) you mention, or does this depend on the CS having only a single holomorphic variable?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero:   I'm not immediately sure about counting for the general case but for elements of a symmetric  tensor product space  to be expressable   as a single product (like an unentangled Bose state) we  need the Segre conditions on the sum coefficients, and for the exterior  product (vertical boxes) we need the Pluecker decomposability relations.